# Disable Fullscreen Button of AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using the `AVPlayerViewController` to embedd videos into my `UIView`:

```
class MyView : PopupContentView {
    var player : AVPlayer!;
    var playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController!;

    override func awakeFromNib() {

    }

    override func setupView() {
        super.setupView();

        self.setupVideo();
    }

    deinit {
        self.player.pause();
        self.player = nil;
    }

    func setupVideo() {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Lebensqualitaet", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        self.player = AVPlayer(url: url);

        self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController();
        self.playerViewController.player = self.player;

        self.callbacks.getAVCallbacks()?.setAVPlayerReference(player: self.playerViewController.player!);
        self.callbacks.getViewControllerToPresent().addChildViewController(self.playerViewController);

        self.addSubview(self.playerViewController.view);

        self.playerViewController.view.frame = self.frame;
    }
}
```

In this `AVPlayerViewController` there is a button to set the video to fullscreen. Is it possible to disable this button? My Problem is that if the video is set to fullscreen and after that fullscreen is getting disabled again the whole view is closing and I dont know why. That is why I simply want to disable the fullscreen mode.

Comment: Have you ever found out or worked around your problem?

Comment: No. Never. But I found a good player implementation where you can disable it: https://github.com/BrikerMan/BMPlayer

Comment: Second that motion - use the BMPlayer and follow the instructions here: https://github.com/BrikerMan/BMPlayer/issues/175